# With the linear approx. of $f(x)= sin(x)$ around $0$ Calculate $\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{sin\theta}{\theta}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

With the linear approximation of $f(x)= sin(x)$ around $0$, calculate:
$$ \lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$$

Figured I have to use L'Hospital's Rule, but I think I don't get how to calculate the derivative of theta.
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}=\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{d\theta}\sin\theta}{\frac{d}{d\theta}\theta}=\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\cos \theta}{1}=\frac{\cos 0}{1}=1$$

Comment: Theta is just some sort of variable. You could change it all to $\frac{sinx}{x}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have already pointed out that you simply use that for $\theta$ small $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ and you can use this to calculate the limit. Only for completion of this answer, you then have
$$
\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta} = \lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\theta}{\theta} = \lim_{\theta \to 0} 1 = 1.
$$

I wanted to give also a quick comment on your use of L'Hopital's Rule:

[image: Calculations]

(I have included your original image since)

It is not (in general) correct that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \color{red}{\lim_{x\to 0}}\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.
$$
(You, of course, forgot the limit in front of the fractions.)

What is true, in your situation, is that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.
$$
You have to remember to take the derivative of the top and the bottom separately. It looks like this is actually what you end up doing, but the notation is important. Using incorrect notation can cause a lot of confusion (In particular when grading written work and the teacher is tired :))

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Very impressive answer!

Comment: @JesterJinx: You are welcome!

Comment: Would you mind telling me exactly why $sin(x)≈x$?

Comment: @JesterJinx: There is a deeper way to see this. It is true that $\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^n$. That you use the linear approximation simply means you just take the first term in this series. And the first term is $x$. See more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition

Answer (score 5):

Two ways to go about doing this:

**Taylor Series**

We can use the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\ldots$$

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^3}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+\ldots$$

So $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$

**Squeeze Theorem**

[image]

The area of the triangle in the image above is $\displaystyle \frac{\sin\theta}{2\cos\theta}$.

The area of the small circular sector is $\displaystyle \frac{\theta}{2}$.

The area of the big circular sector is $\displaystyle \frac{\theta}{2\cos^2\theta}$.

So, for $0<\theta<\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have

$$\displaystyle \frac{\theta}{2}<\displaystyle \frac{\sin\theta}{2\cos\theta}<\displaystyle \frac{\theta}{2\cos^2\theta}$$

Since $\displaystyle \frac{2\cos\theta}{\theta}$ is positive for $0<\theta<\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$, we can multiply by $\displaystyle \frac{2\cos\theta}{\theta}$:

$$\cos\theta<\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}<\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$$

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{\theta \to 0} \cos\theta=\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{1}{\cos\theta}=1$, we can use Squeeze Theorem to conclude $\displaystyle \lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$.

Comment: Your second approach which makes most sense out of all the answers here. +1

Answer (score 2):

It says to use the linear approximation of $\sin \theta$ around $\theta=0$ which is $\sin \theta \approx \theta$. Therefore, we have:
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}=\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac\theta\theta=1$$

Answer (score 2):

The hint tells you to use the linear approximation of $\sin(x)$ near $0$.

For $x$ near $0$, $\sin(x) \approx x.$ So for $x$ near $0$,

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \approx \frac{x}{x} = 1.$$

Thus $\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the approximation of functions around $0$ can be obtained from Maclaurin series.

Here, you have $sin(x)=x-1/6x^3+...$ as its Maclaurin series,

and so its linear approximation is just the first term, i.e, $sin(x)\approx x$.

As a result, the answer would be $1$.

Comment: People typically refer to these as Taylor Series rather than Bernoulli Series.

Comment: @KenDuna Actually, the Taylor series related to $x=0$ is known as Bernoulli series.

Comment: In most Calculus books (at least in the U.S.) the Taylor series related to $x=0$ is called a Maclaurin Series. But I certainly believe that in some books it is referred to as a Bernoulli series, it would tie in nicely with the Bernoulli numbers. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @KenDuna My bad memory! Thanks for your comment. I made the revision. I meant Maclaurin!!!